# Process of operator &, &&, and |

Tags: binary

Given the following binary numbers ...

a =  00001100
b =  00011100

t = a & b && a | b;

...what is the value of the following expression?

The answer should be: 00000001, could anyone explain the process to me?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about C/C++, open your K&R book and look at the "operators" section. See the syntax and priorities of boolean and binary operators, and Bob should soon be your uncle.

Comment: Seems to be language specific: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be language specific: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages.

I tested it out in C, and got exactly what I (and you) expected:

```
int a  = 0b00011100;
int b  = 0b00001100;
printf("%d\n", a & b);                 // 12                
printf("%d\n", a | b);                 // 28
printf("%d\n", (a & b) && (a | b));    //  1
printf("%d\n", a & b && a | b);        //  1
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what you meant by explaining the process,  so to elaborate, you can think of it like processing the arithmetic problem  3 * 2 + 24 / 6.  You process the * and / first, then add the resultant values.  The result of `a & b` (`a` bitwise and `b`) is whatever bits they share (in this case 0b00001100),  and `a | b`  (`a` bitwise or `b`) is whatever bits either (or both) have.  The `&&` (logical and) of that is 1 because neither value is zero.